# приоритет касаний android

Tags: android, c#, listview, xamarin, swiperefreshlayout

Такая проблем! Я сделал SwipeRefresh и теперь когда прокручиваешь вверх включается свайп, а нужно крутить список доверху. Как исправить этот баг? Есть способ установить приоритет ListView перед Swipe?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/refresher">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <Button
            android:text="Insert"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMainInsert" />
        <ListView
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listViewMain" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Код MainActivity

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


listview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewMain);
            var txt1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);

        refresh = FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.refresher);
        refresh.Refresh += refresher_refresh;

        listview.ItemClick += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (inActionMode)
            {
                adapter.ToggleSelection(e.Position);
                _mode.Title = (adapter.SelectedCount.ToString() + " selected");
                return;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(UpdateItemActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("Id", e.Id);
            StartActivity(intent);
        };

        listview.ItemLongClick += (s, e) =>
         {
             adapter.ToggleSelection(e.Position);
             var hasCheckedItems = adapter.SelectedCount > 0;
             if (hasCheckedItems && _mode == null)
                 _mode = StartActionMode(this);

             else if (!hasCheckedItems && _mode != null)
                 _mode.Finish();

             if (_mode != null)
                 _mode.Title = (adapter.SelectedCount.ToString() + " selected");
         };

        var btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonMainInsert);

        btn.Click += delegate
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(UpdateItemActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
    }


private void refresher_refresh (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        private void worker_DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int a = random.Next(0, 1000);

            Item item1 = new Item { Title = "test" + a , Description = "Descc" + a };
            db.InsertIntoTableItem(item1);
        }
       void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                refresh.Refreshing = false;
                lstSource = db.SelctedTableItem();
                adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, lstSource);
                listview.Adapter = adapter;
                //RegisterForContextMenu(listview);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Покажите код и xml.

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть в `SwipeRefreshLayout` только `ListView`.

Comment: Написано на Xamarin, но я уже привык переводить с Java